# Running javascript after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, telerik, rad-controls

I've been tasked with removing all Telerik controls from our website.  I'm not that good with javascript, so this is a great learning experience for me.  Most of the controls are easy to understand and fairly easy to replace, but I'm stuck on one.  I need to replace the RadScriptBlock in the following code:

```
<telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ConfigurationHandler.getStaticContentBaseURL(Request)%>js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="<%=ConfigurationHandler.getStaticContentBaseURL(Request)%>js/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ConfigurationHandler.getStaticContentBaseURL(Request)%>js/jquery.json-2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ConfigurationHandler.getStaticContentBaseURL(Request)%>js/Portal/main.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="<%=ConfigurationHandler.getStaticContentBaseURL(Request)%>js/Portal/popup.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ConfigurationHandler.getStaticContentBaseURL(Request)%>js/SeoTracking.js" ></script>
```

Based on everything I've read, I think I need to use the following, but I'm at a total loss as to how.  Any help/suggestions/resource would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
new Ajax.Request('/your/url', {
  onSuccess: function(response) {
    // Handle the response content...
  }
});
```

So this ended up being the fix...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:44344/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$.ajax({

    url: 'AjaxOrderStepServer.aspx',
    success: function () {

    debugger;

        var baseurl = ConfigurationHandler.getStaticContentBaseURL(Request);
        var url = baseurl + "/js/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js";
        $.getScript(url);

        url = baseurl + "/js/jquery.json-2.4.min.js";
        $.getScript(url);

        url = baseurl + "/js/Portal/main.js";
        $.getScript(url);

        url = baseurl + "/js/Portal/popup.js";
        $.getScript(url);

        url = baseurl + "/js/SeoTracking.js";
        $.getScript(url);
    }
});
```

Comment: Kudos for coming back to edit in the answer once you figured it out :)

Comment: It would be best to actually post your solution as an answer and then accept it, so that when there are other people down the road browsing questions, they can see that this one has a solution.